# Don't you have to use the same parameter names when calling a method?

Tags: java

In the code below, I've written two methods:

- One that has the variable `test` defined as a String
- One that returns two different outcomes depending on what is typed

I have the variable named `test` in `userInputhere` while the parameter in `Hello` is named `message`. In `userInputhere` I use `test` instead of `message` - why does this work?

Does the parameter not matter when you invoke the `Hello` method?

I get that when entering a method that returns something, it has to be defined and the parameters define further what the method is going to work on, so, I had assumed that, when calling said method from another method, you would have to use the same parameters, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class methodsandparameters {
        static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args){
            userInputhere();
        }

        public static void userInputhere(){
            String test = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(Hello(test));
        }

        public static String Hello(String message){
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi")) {
                return "Hello";
            } else {
                return "Goodbye";       
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It is currently unclear to me what you mean? Are you confused why you can name your variable `test` in `userInputhere` and then use its value as `message` in the `Hello` method?

Comment: Yes ^ that is exactly what I am confused about. I had assumed that, all of the variables had to be named the same in order to use them. So, I got confused when the variable in `Hello` was named `message` and yet still worked when I used this code `System.out.println(Hello(test));`

Comment: Let's assume I would tell you that I would throw a ball to you and you should catch it. Then you don't bother the brand or the product name of that ball, all you need to know is: it is a ball (-> variable type). That generally the same in Java. Both answers explained that very well :).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the parameter names, as you call them, don't match is only one is a parameter. When you call a function you pass it a number of arguments that must match the type and number of parameters a function takes. So if you have a function `add(int x, int y)` it doesn't matter how you call it as long as both arguments are `int`s, they don't have to be named x and y when you call the function.

So a function/method takes parameters and calling a function passes arguments.

Comment: So, the method `Hello` takes the parameters and the function `System.out.println(Hello(test));` takes arguments which are defined within the method `Hello`? This is my understanding of what you said, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `Hello` takes the parameters that the function `System.out.println(Hello(test));` pass (not take). If that is what you mean then yes

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thanks you for answering my original question and clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke the `Hello` method, its parameter (`message`) is contained inside of the Hello method itself. You are allowed to pass any argument to `Hello` as long as it is a string (since `message` is of type String). It does not matter what you pass to `Hello` as long as it resolves to a String. So in your example, the variable `test` works fine because it is a String.

The program is not actually invoking "test" or invoking "message", it is only invoking the `Hello` method which can take any String as an argument.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. So, pretty much, the parameter (`message`) is within Hello and the code `System.out.println(Hello(test));` is merely calling upon `Hello` and using the results given from `test`, right?

Comment: Yes. As long as whatever you pass into `Hello(String message)` is a String, the method will work and use the value of `message`.

Answer (score 1):

The name of a variable **only** matters within it's *scope* (i.e. where you can reference it)<sup>[1]</sup>.

For a method parameter, that's only in the body of that method.

Outside of that method, the only thing that matters is the type - `String`, in this case. As long as you pass it something of the same type, or a type that can be automatically converted to the given type, it's happy - whatever you called the parameter (`message`, in this case) will be given the value of whatever you passed to your function in that position in the arguments and each time you use that parameter name in the method, you'll be using that value that's been given to it (at least until you reassign it in your method, by saying `message = ...`).

You can also do things like `Hello(input.nextLine())` or `Hello("Hi")` - no need to use a temporary variable.

---

[1]: Until you start talking about [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) (but no need to worry about that yet).